# How to combine the two awk files into one?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is a original awk file ,i want to format it.

**input content----original awk file named test.txt**

```
awk 'BEGIN {maxlength = 0}\
     {\
           if (length($0) > maxlength) {\
                maxlength = length($0);\
                longest = $0;\
           }\
     }\
     END   {print longest}' somefile
```

**expected output----well-formatted awk file**

```
awk 'BEGIN {maxlength = 0}                      \
     {                                          \
           if (length($0) > maxlength) {        \
                maxlength = length($0);         \
                longest = $0;                   \
           }                                    \
     }                                          \
     END   {print longest}' somefile
```

step1:to get the longest line and chracters number

**step1.awk**

```
#! /usr/bin/awk 
BEGIN {max =0 }
{
    if (length($0) > max) { max = length($0)}
}
END {print max}
```

awk -f step1.awk test.txt

Now the max length for all lines is 50.

step2 to put \ in the position 50+2=52.

**step2.awk**

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
{
if($0 ~ /\\$/){
    gsub(/\\$/,"",$0);
    printf("%-*s\\\n",n,$0);
    }
else{
    printf("%s\n",$0);
    }
}
```

awk -f step2.awk -v n=52 test.txt > well_formatted.txt

How to combine step1 and step2 into only one step,and combine step1.awk and step2.awk as one awk file?

Comment: post the input content and the expected output to get a quick help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better version, where you can use `sub()` instead of `gsub()`, and to avoid testing the same regexp twice `sub(/\\$/,""){ ... }`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ 
             if(length>max)max = length 
             next
     }
     sub(/\\$/,""){
             printf "%-*s\\\n", max+2, $0
             next
     }1' test.txt test.txt
```

**Explanation**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{                             # Here we read file and will find, 
                                          # max length of line in file
                                          # FNR==NR is true when awk reads first file

             if(length>max)max = length   # find max length 
             next                         # stop processing go to next line
     }
     sub(/\\$/,""){                       # Here we read same file once again, 
                                          # if substitution was made for the regex in record then

             printf "%-*s\\\n", max+2, $0 # printf with format string max+2
             next                         # go to next line
     }1                                   # 1 at the end does default operation print $0, 
                                          # nothing but your else statement printf("%s\n",$0) in step2 
     ' test.txt test.txt
```

You have not shown us, what's your input and expected output, with some assumption,

**if your input looks like below**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat f
123      \
\
12345     
123456   \
1234567  \
123456789 
12345
```

**You get output as follows**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk 'FNR==NR{ if(length>max)max = length; next}
sub(/\\$/,"",$0){ printf "%-*s\\\n",max+2,$0; next }1' f f
123         \
            \
12345     
123456      \
1234567     \
123456789 
12345
```

Comment: you may use `sub()` instead of `gsub()` to keep originality of your code, I didn't modify, just combined into one

Comment: nearly the same code (some minor difference for the purpose) at same time so +1 (but is it objective :-D ).

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Thank you, OP hasn't shown anything other than code :)

Comment: The only remaining issue is one inherited from the question - it counts characters so a tab is 1 character but prints looking like up to 8 (typically) so the backslashes in the output won't necessarily look aligned. Try converting all sequences of 8 blanks in the input file to tab characters and then run your tool to see what I mean. If you want to make this "work" robustly (assuming "work" means just getting that right character correct) then you need `pr -e -t file | awk '...'` but then you can't run awk on the input twice as currently and any literal tabs in print strings will get converted

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
   # first round 
   FNR == NR {
      # take longest (compare and take longest line by line)
      M = M < (l = length( $0) ) ? l : M
      # go to next line
      next
      }

   # for every line of second round (due to previous next) that finish by /
   /[/]$/ {          
      # if a modification is needed
      if ( ( l = length( $0) ) < M ) {
         # add the missing space (using sprintf "%9s" for 9 spaces)
         sub( /[/]$/, sprintf( "%" (M - l) "s/", ""))
         }
      }
  # print all line [modified or not] (7 is private joke but important is <> 0 )
  7
  ' test.txt test.txt
```

Note:

- twice the file at the end is mandatory for reading twice the file
- assume that there is nothing after last / (no space). Could be easily adapted but not the purpose
- assume that line without / are not modified but still printed

Comment: Seems some confusion between forward and backslashes (maybe the confusion is mine :). `/[/]$/` for me also causes syntax error.

Comment: liked your `7 is private joke` ++, I think its backslash isn't it ?

Comment: no, it comes from another stack user that explain that 7 is faster to type on his keyboard than 1 so he take 7, i keep the habit with a smile everytime i choose this in my code (and another when people try to understand why, reading the code)

Comment: Ah yes, nothing funnier than obfuscating code :-). Talking of which - never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks FAR too much like the number `1`.

Comment: In my keyboard layout `}` is produced with AltGr-0. If it was under any other number - for example 9 - it would be fast to type AltGr-9 9 to end the last code block and print: `...}9` but it has to be under 0. Whoever designed this layout sure wasn't an awk wiz.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for GNU awk. Two runs, first one finds the max length and the second one outputs. `FS` is set to `""` so that each char goes on its field and the last char will in `$NF`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==FNR{m=(m<NF?NF:m);next}$NF=="\\"{$NF=sprintf("% "m-NF+2"s",$NF)}1' file file
```

Output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {maxlength = 0}               \
     {                                   \
           if (length($0) > maxlength) { \
                maxlength = length($0);  \
                longest = $0;            \
           }                             \
     }                                   \
     END   {print longest}' somefile
```

Explained:

```
BEGIN     { FS=OFS="" }                         # each char on different field
NR==FNR   { m=(m<NF?NF:m); next }               # find m ax length
$NF=="\\" { $NF=sprintf("% " m-NF+2 "s",$NF) }  # NF gets space padded
1                                               # output
```

If you want the `\`s further away from the code, change that `2` in `sprintf` to suit your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
wc -L test.txt | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -I{} sed -i -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,'{}'\}$/& /;ta' test.txt && sed -i -r 's/(\\)([ ]*)$/\2\1/g' test.txt
```